# Java generics: Bound mismatch.Looking for the valid substitute

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a couple of generic classes:

```
public interface Data<E> {}
public interface Clonable<E extends Clonable<E>> {}
public interface NaturalNumberInterface extends Data<NaturalNumberInterface> {}
public class NaturalNumber implements NaturalNumberInterface {}
public interface SetInterface<E extends Data<E>> extends Clonable<SetInterface<E>> {}
public class Set<E extends Data<E>> implements SetInterface<E> {}
```

When I'm trying to create the new instance of Set `Set<NaturalNumber> s=new Set<NaturalNumber>();` compiler says:

> `NaturalNumber` is not valid substitute for the type parameter `<E extends Data<E>>` of the type `Set<E>`

Maybe you can help me to find the mistake, cause I spent a long time and didn't find the solution.

Comment: how is `Data` defined?

Comment: also how SetInterface is defined. Please provide compiling code at least

Comment: As OP likes my answer, seems that my assumption was correct. I edited the question to reflect it. `List` and `ListInterface` seem to be unnecessary for this question, so I removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your `SetInterface` is defined in the same way as `ListInterface` and `Data` is just `interface Data<T>`.

The generic argument of `SetInterface` is [F-bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification): `E extends Data<E>`. In your current code `NaturalNumber` type extends `Data<NaturalNumberInterface>`. So if `E` is `NaturalNumber`, then condition is violated as it should extend more specific type `Data<NaturalNumber>`.

You should use F-bounds for `NaturalNumberInterface` as well:

```
public interface NaturalNumberInterface<T extends NaturalNumberInterface<T>> extends Data<T>
public class NaturalNumber implements NaturalNumberInterface<NaturalNumber>
```

This way it will work.